# Calculating effect size for a binomial test?

Tags: binomial-distribution, statistical-power, effect-size

I am running a power analysis for my one-tailed binomial test, but I have no idea how to calculate the effect size. I have 31 trials, and of those 8 lead to a desired result. The null hypothesis expects 66% of these trials to have the desired result. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Other users (see [similar thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176847/effect-size-of-a-binomial-test-and-its-relation-to-other-measures-of-effect-size)) have recommended using [Relative Risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_risk) as an effect size for binomial tests; although, the [Odds Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio) or [Cohen's h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_h) seem like fair choices as well.

In your case the Relative Risk would be calculated as follows:
$RR=\frac{8/31}{66/100}\approx.39$