# In search for the exact "z-value" of the binomial test

Tags: binomial-distribution, standard-error

I want to explain my second-semester psychology students why we have sample-SNRs (Signal to Noise Ratios) all over the place (t, z, F, Chi²). They are also called statistical test values. But we have nothing like that for the binomial test. At least not an exact one. We only have z as an approximation.
My students are trained in frequentist statistics only (time constraints and me not feeling comfortable teaching bayesian concepts yet).

In more detail

a)
The test statistics z, t, F etc. can be interpreted as sample Signal-to-Noise-Ratios (SNR).
But: A SNR for the classic / frequentist binomial test does not seem to exist. SPSS and JASP do not report one and an extensive google(scholar) search did not reveal one.
Who does know the formula for an exact SNR or "test statistic" of the binomial test?

b)
When the binomial distribution is symetric the z-value of the z-Test of proportions is a good approximation of a SNR. And if not symetric or for very small n, it would need a correction of some sort... but which one?

For the z-Test of proportions the empirical z-value or SNR is:

```
SNR = z
= Signal / Noise
= Cohens g / Standard error of proportions
= (p - p0) / Square Root of (p0 · (1 - p0) / n)
```

- with p as the observed proportion and
- with p0 as the reference value, sometimes called Pi0 or Pi.
- with n as the number of observations

So how to calculate this exactly for the binomial test specificallywhen n small and p unequal 0.5?

Comment: I tried to be more precise with my question and splitted it in two parts. Maybe now someone has a partly answer?

Comment: Andrew Gelman over on Statistical Modeling Causal (https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2022/12/19/signal-to-noise-ratio-and-statistical-tests/) tried to answer an older version of this question kind of broadly - but not specific to the binomial test. So I wonder, if my question is still not clearly formulated. If so - please tell me. Which parts of the question are not clearly formulated?

Comment: I haven't seen the expression *signal-to-noise ratio* used very often in statistics. As A. Gelman says *there’s no precise definition of signal-to-noise ratio*. If SNR is a synonym or a close relative to *effect size* then see if this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176847/effect-size-of-a-binomial-test-and-its-relation-to-other-measures-of-effect-size) and [Cohen's H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_h) help.

Comment: Where I come from SNR is used as a synonym for z t F Chi² values. Because they are calculated as Signal / Noise = Effect / Standard Error of the Effect.

SNR is not a synonym to effect size.

Comment: To quote Stephen Senn: "What is plotted are the distributions of the t-statistics, the signal to noise ratios [...]" (https://errorstatistics.com/2013/07/14/stephen-senn-indefinite-irrelevance-2)

Comment: In my understanding, SNR is an intuitive proxy for e.g. the t-statistics and this how S. Senn uses it there. However, while the t-statistics (or z-score, etc) is clearly defined, the SNR is not. The closest I can think of for the binomial test is Cohen's H. But again, there isn't a definition of SNR, it seems to me.

Comment: Also a search for "t-values as signal to noise ratio" gives many results that mention the interpretation of t-values as signal-to-noise-ratios. Substitute t with z etc. in the search string for the others.

Comment: Sure, I haven't said SNR is unheard-of, I just said I haven't seen it very often (I come from bioinformatics, if that matters). Anyway, I think the main point is that SNR is not clearly defined, it's more of an intuitive expression. Similar to "dispersion" in place of "standard deviation" or "central tendency" instead of "median".

Comment: Cohen's H is news to me. Thanks. However I am not in search of the binomial tests effect size. I was already able to calculate it with Cohens g, as stated in the G*Power manual: Cohen's g = p− p0 with small 0.05 medium 0.15 large 0.25. And that SNR is not clearly defined should not be a problem to be able to calculate it for the binomial test, since we found ways to calculate it for e.g. the t-Test.

Comment: Why couldn't you call the binomial test's p-value prediction as a test statistic (or SNR if you will) that just happens to be uniformly distributed in the internal [0, 1]?  And you could say that the step with other statistics where you have to integrate some pdf up to the value of the statistic is trivially easy because the integral of a uniform [0, 1] pdf up to value x is always x?  Is the issue that the "SNR" isn't easily parsable into a pseudo-signal numerator and a pseudo-noise denominator?

Comment: Thank you for your question! Yes. That is exactly the issue. For z- or t-values we often say, that a SNR of roughly 2 to 1 (signal 2 times stronger than noise) is sufficient to call the signal significant. Or if you go for alpha 1% you need a SNR of roughly 3:1. This is a very easy thing to grasp for my students. The interpretation of the p-value is much harder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since nobody could answer my Question I asked the KI and got a reasonable response :). It does not make me happy, but sounds good enough for me, to let this rest. Since the answer is lengthy I highlighted the juicy bits.

"Hello, this is Bing. I’m happy to help you with your question.

According to 1, the binomial test is a way to test hypotheses about the probability of success in a binomial experiment. The test statistic for the binomial test is:

b(x; n, p) = nCx * px * (1 - p)n - x

where x is the number of successes, n is the number of trials, p is the hypothesized probability of success, and nCx is the binomial coefficient.

The binomial test can be one-tailed or two-tailed depending on whether you want to test if the observed probability is less than, greater than, or different from the hypothesized probability.

**The binomial test does not have a standard error or a signal-to-noise ratio like other tests because it does not rely on any assumptions about the sampling distribution of the test statistic.** Instead, it calculates the exact probability of observing x successes out of n trials under the null hypothesis.

However, when n is large and p is close to 0.5, the binomial distribution can be approximated by a normal distribution with mean np and variance np(1-p). In this case, you can use a z-test of proportions as an approximation of the binomial test. The z-test has a standard error and a signal-to-noise ratio given by:

SE = sqrt(p(1-p)/n) SNR = (p - p0) / SE

where p0 is the hypothesized probability under the null hypothesis.

**When n is small or p is far from 0.5, you can use a correction factor to adjust for the discrepancy between the binomial and normal distributions. One common correction factor is called Yates’ continuity correction2, which subtracts 0.5 from |p - p0| before calculating SNR.**

I hope this helps you explain your students why we have different types of test statistics for different types of tests.

sources

1. statisticshowto.com
2. statisticshowto.com
3. bing.com
4. en.wikipedia.org
5. byjus.com"